# Is there a way to intercept multiple requests linked by an "OR" conditional operator?

Tags: node.js, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am a beginner with cypress. I've been looking for a way to intercept API calls to at least one of multiple URLs.
Let's say a button is clicked and something like this code is executed to check if a list of requests were called :

```
cy.get('@request1').should('have.been.called').log(`Request was made to 'REQUEST1_URL'`) 
OR 
cy.get('@request2').should('have.been.called').log(`Request was made to ''REQUEST2_URL'`)
```

I want to check if a request was sent to one url or the other, or both.

Has anyone encountered this problem before ? Any contribution is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why after the button is clicked there are two possible API calls? Generally speaking you use wildcard characters in the URL to match. Also `cy.get()` is wrong - you need `cy.wait()`.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR You can use `cy.get()` with a request when you pair it with the `cy.spy()` like this : 
`cy.intercept(
      Cypress.env('REQUEST1_URL')
      ,
      cy.spy().as('request1')
    )
`

Comment: Also there are two possible api calls, depending on previous user actions, the callback can choose to send a request to URL1 or URL2 depending on the state of the app. I want to intercept either one of these requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you use in the intercept should be general enough to catch both calls.

For example if the calls have `/api/` in common, this catches both

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/*')   // note wildcards in the URL
  .as('apiRequest')

cy.visit('/')
cy.wait('@apiRequest')
```

If you have more paths in the url than you need to catch, for example `/api/dogs/` `/api/cats/` and `/api/pigs/`, then use a function to weed out the ones you want

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/*', (req) => {
  if (req.url.includes('dogs') || req.url.includes('cats') {   // no pigs
    req.alias = 'dogsOrCats'                                   // set alias
  }
})

cy.visit('/')
cy.wait('@dogsOrCats')
```

---

**Catching 0, 1, or 2 URLs**

This is a bit tricky, if the number of calls isn't known then you have to know within what time frame they would be made.

To catch **requests** which you are fired fairly quickly by the app

```js
let count = 0;
cy.intercept('**/api/*', (req) => {
  count = count +1;
})

cy.visit('/')
cy.wait(3000)   // wait to see if calls are fired
cy.then(() => {
  cy.wrap(count).should('be.gt', 0)  // 0 calls fails, 1 or 2 passes
})
```

Comment: Sadly, that wouldn't work in my case because the URLs used in the intercept are completely different

Comment: Actually there's no such thing as completely different - if you just use `*` it will match everything. Then you just need do the cats and dogs filter on the URL to find the ones you want, and apply the alias dynamically.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, I'll give that a shot